# prove the set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Prove that the set $$M = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : |f(x)+f'(x)| < 1\}$$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

Does my proof work?
I can rewrite the set
\begin{align}
M & = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : -1 < f(x)+f'(x) < 1\} \\ & = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x)+f'(x) > -1\} \cap \{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x)+f'(x) < 1\}
\end{align}
$f$ is measurable (because it is continuous) and $f'$ is measurable (easy to check), we have the function $f+f'$ is measurable. Then both sets are measurables (there is a theorem that says that if a function $h$ is measurable, 
$\{h < \alpha\}$ and $\{h > \alpha\}$ are measurable.)
Hence $M$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set because is a numerable intersection of measurable sets.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea.

Comment: Also, since $|\cdot|$ is continuous, you have the function $x \mapsto |f(x)+f'(x)|$ is measurable,